# How to compare two files for non-printing characters

Tags: unix, diff

To share a configuration file between two computers, I emailed the file to myself via my gmail account.  When I loaded the conf on the second computer, the program had trouble reading every line.  Suspecting a problem with newline characters (dos vs unix style), I opened the file up in gvim.  I didn't see any ^M's in there as I suspected.  A 'set list' didn't show anything strange - just the text of the file with every line terminated by '$' as I expected.  It looks perfectly fine.  A cat of the file looks just as I'd expect it to.

Out of desperation, I moved the file out of the way and manually retyped the contents of the file in a split vim session (it's only about 20 lines).  I ran a gvim -d on the two files, and that showed no differences.

I ran the program that uses the config file, and sure enough, it was now able to read the newly typed file just fine.

I md5sum'd the two files, and they do have different sums.  I ran a diff on the original file and the newly typed file and it shows that every single line of the files are different.  But I can't see any difference in the output.

So, I'm curious: what tool can I use to see the differences between these two files?  gvim -d shows no differences, and diff shows that they are all different, but the output looks identical.

If I could attach the two files, I would.

Comment: You can use `file` on those two files, which tells you also some unusual line endlings. I would bet that `diff -b` (ignores changes in whitespaces) reports also that the files are identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `od -c` to dump each file as hex, then diff the results.

```
od -c file1 > file1.hex
od -c file2 > file2.hex
diff file1.hex file2.hex
```

Comment: @firebush you can also use `od -c` to see all characters in the file (including `\n` and `\r`).

Comment: @terdon Good suggestion to use `-c` instead of `-x`.  That is more readable output.  I've made the change to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think an easier way is just to pipe your diff output through `cat -t`

```
diff file1 file2 | cat -t
```

This method also works simply with various version control tools

```
bzr diff | cat -t
```

Comment: In my case, this method is simpler, shorter, more readable. There is only one different, non-printable, character between two otherwise identical ASCII files. The accepted answer's output is longer, harder to grasp where the difference occurs.